# How do I do a custom exit status in my Java program written in jRuby?

Tags: java, ant, jruby

I am working on a generalized base of a validation util which I want distribute as a JAR and automate using Ant. Using Java alone, I can do something like

```
...
int validationResults = this.validate();
System.exit(validationResults) // via Ant: 1 = "BUILD FAILED", 0 = "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"
...
```

to use the validation util in scheduled builds using CI-systems.

I am however writing this in jRuby instead of Java (for learning). I have tried the below ways but they do not trigger "BUILD FAILED" in Ant.

```
java.lang.System.exit(1) # using "require 'java'" at the the top of the file
Kernel.exit 1
exit 1
```

I have seen tickets in the jRuby issue tracker about this (for example [JRUBY-1650](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-1650)) but I have not managed to find a solution to my problem.

I am running jRuby v1.6.6 and Warbler v1.3.2. The Ant target looks like this:

```
<target name="validate">
  <java jar="./validator.jar" fork="true" />
</target>
```

Is it me not doing it right, or does jRuby not support this (yet)?

Comment: How do you invoke your jRuby code from Ant ?

Comment: The issue you refer to is fixed since jRuby 1.5 and it only concerns a "0" exit code. Non-zero has always worked.

Comment: The problem was a missing failonerror attribute in the ant target. See the accepted answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you start your jRuby code from the [`java` Ant task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html).

To get Ant fail in case of a non-zero exit code from your jRuby process, you have to set the `failonerror` attribute of the java task to `true`.

Comment: I forgot to add the failonerror attribute. Adding it solved my problem. Sorry for leaving the ant target out, I updated the question with it for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a kludge I use to trigger a build failure when ant is otherwise unable to recognise the exit code. It requires `ant-contrib`.

In ant:

```
<delete file="${java.io.tmpdir}/build-executable-error"/>
<exec executable= ... />

<if>
    <resourceexists>
        <file file="${java.io.tmpdir}/build-executable-error"/>
    </resourceexists>
    <then>
        <loadfile srcfile="${java.io.tmpdir}/build-executable-error"
                  property="build.failure.message"/>
        <fail message="${build.failure.message}"/>
    </then>
</if>
```

The executable is then responsible for creating and populating the file `${java.io.tmpdir}/build-executable-error` on any error scenario.

Comment: Good idea. It is necessary to do that for a non Java process. In this question scenario, jRuby is a Java code that can be started with <java> task, forked or not.

Comment: `failonerror`? Ugh, I didn't think it would be the obvious solution.